# ASP.NET MVC Enitity framework calculate quotient

Tags: asp.net, math, model-view-controller

How can I get quotient of 10 / 100 in asp.net mvc controller.I always get 0 return.Is there anyway to get the right answer 0.1.

```
decimal newpercent = percent / 100;
```

Comment: If i am right ? then please marked it as answer by clicking the check sign on the left! -.

Comment: `decimal newpercent = (decimal)percent / 100;`

Comment: It work. Thank you Alex Kudryashev

Answer (score 0):

You were doing integer division so that's why you will get 0 in the output.

try this it will work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double test =  10.0 / 100.0;
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to See that. Mark it as a answer on clicking the 'check' sign on the left side. -thank you. @KhinThitsar